# Change the default caret sign of select drop down

Tags: html, css

Is there any way through which we can change the dropdown default caret sign. I found a solution on web through which we can do that, but that require an image to be loaded in background. Below is the css which I used

But I am looking for a solution through which the image could be replaced with some text content like font awesome and other font libraries does. Any help is appreciated.

```
select {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
    background-size: 9px;
    padding-right: 22px !important;
    background-image: url('http://cache.freescale.com/files/graphic/other/UP_DOWN_ARROW.jpg');
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 0px !important;
    height: 32px;
}

select::-ms-expand {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Use plugins like select2 or chosen

Comment: Currently there is no way to alert the style of a select element (beyond padding, borders, etc.). The only way this can be done is by adding additional HTML around the select and styling that.
See: http://bavotasan.com/2011/style-select-box-using-only-css/ or https://css-tricks.com/dropdown-default-styling/